# Bootstrap drowdown works locally but not in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, railstutorial.org

Currently working on the Ruby on Rails tutorial (railstutorial.org) and in Chap 8.  you make a dropdown menu using bootstrap classes for signed in users.

To make this work the book says to include

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
```

in your application.js file.

This does not work locally or on heroku.

However:

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

works locally, not on heroku. This also creates a ton of error messages in the console (Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'fn' of undefined)

---

Every stack thread and googled page I go to says that bootstrap goes first in local and jquery first in production. Meanwile I'm pulling my hair out.

git hub: https://github.com/nelsonkhan/sample_app
 heroku: https://guarded-shelf-3017.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have all 4 of these:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: would you please flesh this out a bit to help the OP understand what the problem was? (reviewer)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your assets are properly compiled when you deploy on heroku. Check here for more details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: I just precompiled everything using rake assets:precompile --trace. Still not working :/

Answer (score 0):

Changing `production.rb` helped for me

```
 config.assets.compile = true
```